# Cannot write to a HttpContext.Response in AuthenticationHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

When in my custom `AuthenticationHandler` I want to write some data into `HttpContext.Response` like this:

```
protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
    await Context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new SomeObject(), Context.RequestAborted);
    return AuthenticateResult.Fail("something went wrong");
}
```

I always get exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.

With these stack traces:

> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Handle|0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---

And:

> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

Thought with this error my request is aborted and I don't get any response. If after writing to response I call `Response.CompleteAsync()` then exception is still thrown, but I get response.

Additionally, I don't have any custom middleware. How can I fix this?

Comment: What line is it failing at? The `WriteAsJsonAsync` line?

Comment: Can you capture and post the stack trace?

Comment: I do not know for sure (not having tried what you're trying) but I wonder whether the async nature of this call means that the app has continued to work on processing the request while your async method is running. Sort of a race condition, in other words!

Comment: Yes, this is failing at `WriteAsJsonAsync` line. I edited my question and have added stack trace.

Comment: I don't think it's the `WriteAsJsonAsync`. It must be at `Fail` since you're trying to set another error here while you have already done that with `RequestAborted`. This would explain why you're getting the `InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.`

Comment: The response status code goes in the first line of the HTTP response. So if you've already written the body, it's too late to write the status. You can get around this (I think) by setting [Response.Buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.buffer?view=netframework-4.8) to true.

Comment: I did it using `Context.Response.OnStarting().` Here I created a lambda expression that invokes `Context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync`. But I'm not sure whether it's good solution. What do you think?